# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Linguistics has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Draconis]

[image: curiousdannii]

[image: Alenanno]

Please thank them for volunteering!

We also wanted to pose a suggestion to the community. As you can see from the results of the voting, [Prash](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/126/prash) came in fourth by only 2 votes. Prash has contributed a lot to the community over the years and has served as an active Pro-Temp Moderator. We wanted to ask if you all wanted to have four moderators for the site since this is a very unique situation. If that works for the community, Prash will retain their diamonds.

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: lemontree]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5953466221461504).

Comment: Since Prash was allowed to remain a moderator, and ordinarily on a graduation election pro-tem mods who don't win lose their privileges, can they be added to the election page as "called in after the election to meet additional demand"? This was done on some previous Stack Overflow elections, so it has precedent.

Comment: @gparyani there isn't away for me to edit the election page in that way with the automations but both Prash and Alenanno are now listed on the elections result page. https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/election/1

Comment: So the table on https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/election cannot be changed as was possible in the past?

Answer (score 7):

Thank you Rosie!

Also thanks to everyone that participated and voted. I am totally in favor in having a fourth moderator as I believe Prash has contributed a lot to this site. I know that.

Congratulations to the ones that gained their diamond and thanks to the ones also that gave me their trust to continue being an active part of the moderator team.

Much love!

Answer (score 5):

Congrats to the new moderators elected, you will make a great team. I also second Rosie's suggestion of keeping Prash as a moderator.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, thank you Linguistics.SE for your faith in me, with so many other great candidates I truly wasn't expecting this.

I definitely support Prash making the cut as well.

Thank you to Mellifluous for also putting your name forward, and to lemontree for your years of service here.